# Configure Freeradius To Only Authenticate Members Of Specific FreeIPA LDAP Groups

Tags: freeradius

I'm having trouble configuring Freeradius to only allow authentication from specific groups LDAP groups in FreeIPA. Currently, Freeradius is able to authenticate any LDAP users as long as the correct credentials are provided.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide FreeRADIUS version, and your basic group layout and referencing scheme. i.e. are group names/DNs listed as attribute (memberOf) values in the user object, or do group objects have lists of user names/DNs listed as attributes (member).

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell thx for your help. The FreeRADIUS version is 3.0.13 and the DNs are listed as attribute (memberOf) values in the user object. See below

Comment: [root@radius ~]# ldapsearch -x -v -W -D 'cn=Directory Manager' uid=userName

# userName, users, compat, mydomain.com
dn: uid=userName,cn=users,cn=compat,dc=mydomain,dc=com

objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: ipaOverrideTarget

mepManagedEntry: cn=userName,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=mydomain,dc=com

memberOf: cn=Radius server,cn=roles,cn=accounts,dc=mydomain,dc=com

memberOf: cn=Radius services,cn=privileges,cn=pbac,dc=mydomain,dc=com
memberOf: cn=ipaNTHash service read,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=mydomain,dc=com

memberOf: cn=netusers,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=mydomain,dc=com